# Creating New Array when Second Array is > 0

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

I'm running Python 2.7.

I have an array called "altitude" with the following points

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

I also have an array called "arming_pin"

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1]
```

In my program when arming_pin is greater than zero I would like to use the "altitude" array data points and ignore the previous points when `"arming_pin"` was = to 0. I would like to call this new array `"altitude_new"`. The "altitude_new" array would look like:

```
[6,7,8,9]
```

How can I do create this new array in python? Using a conditional statement of some sort?

Comment: `[j for i,j in enumerate(altitude) if arming_pin[i]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function within a list comprehension to filter your array :

```
>>> f=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> sec=[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1]
>>> 
>>> [i for i,j in zip(f,sec) if j]
[6, 7, 8, 9]
```

You can also use `itertools.compress` Which is more efficient when you are dealing with larger list :

```
>>> from itertools import compress
>>> list(compress(f,sec))
[6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Or use `numpy.compress`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.compress(sec,f)
array([6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Comment: @AndrewReardon Welcome, so what about accepting my answer?;)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the [compress method from itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.compress) module, this way:

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> l1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> l2 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1]
>>> list(it.compress(l1,l2))
[6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
altitude_new=[]
for i in range(len(arming_pin)):
    if arming_pin[i] == 1:
        altitude_new.append(altitude[i])
```

one line list comprehension:

```
altitude_new = [altitude[i] for i in range(len(arming_pin)) if arming_pin[i]]
```

night shade's comment is now more succinct [j for i,j in enumerate(altitude) if arming_pin[i]]

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, is meant to be easy to understand for people not accustomed to list comprehension.

```
altitude = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
arming_pin = [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1]

altitude_new = []

idx = 0 # track the indices
for item in arming_pin:
    if item > 0:
        altitude_new.append(altitude[idx])
    idx += 1

print altitude_new
>>> [6, 7, 8, 9]
```